Twilio Error 32017 Carrier blocked call due to calling number (caller ID)
I am trying to use twilio and make.com to create an outbound Agent, I made the connection, it worked for the first few times but after a few tries I cannot work with it. When I check the call logs I get the following error, the API calls and everything is working properly.
I tried calling a different number but it does not resolve this issue.

I hope to find you well.
Can you post the details of this integration? Which API endpoint are Twilio using? Twilio has no limitations for making calls via API.

So I am using make.com for automation. I have connected Twilio to Vapi AI. On vapi AI I tested the connection with the Vapi API reference. When I integrated it in make.com it stopped and checking the call logs I found this error

Can you tell me if something appears on this page?
https://console.twilio.com/us1/monitor/logs/debugger/errors

Yes so I get the complete error log.
Message
Carrier blocked call due to calling number (caller ID).
Error Description
Intermediary / Carrier Analytics blocked call due to poor reputation score on the telephone number

This usually occurs because you are not using a verified CallerID in the Twilio environment:
https://help.twilio.com/articles/223180048-Adding-a-Verified-Phone-Number-or-Caller-ID-with-Twilio
NOTE: Always use both the to and the from standard E164 e.g.:
+551132301337
+COUNTRY CODE+AREA CODE+PHONE
